# Css select for span class using webdriver C#

Tags: c#, css-selectors, webdriver

I need to click on following element.

```
<span tabindex="-1" class="ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu" style="max-width: 150px;" 
command="account|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.NewRecordFromGrid"> New </span>
```

what css selector can I use?

Answer (score 1):

$('.ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu').click();
Or any way you want to use this selector.

Or without jquery

var abc = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu");
abc.click();

Comment: You can accept this answer also if you found it best!